# How can I read data from USB with Python? (pyUSB)

Tags: python, usb

I´m trying to read the data recived via USB on python (Linux). I´m new on python.

I found pyUSB but i dont know how to use, I have some issues with something called libusb.

I tried this code:

```
import usb
import usb.backend.libusb1 as libusb1

backend = libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda _: "LibUSB/MS64/dll/libusb-1.0.dll")
dev = usb.core.find(backend=backend)

print(dev)
```

But i have the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_Disco_Local\Python\_proyectos\_pruebaUSB_2\prueba1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import usb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb'
```

Comment: Any code sample you have problem with? What have you tried already?

Comment: Did you mount the USB?

Comment: updated whit problems and  trials @h4z3

Comment: I plugged in an USB @ToniSredanović

Comment: Did you install `PyUSB`? If not you can do it with `pip install pyusb`.